# Is this an uncatchable fatal error?

Tags: php, nginx, silex

I'm writing an application, where I thought all the errors were being handled, including fatal ones.

But now I found one error that results in a white screen, and the error only shows up in the webserver log.

```
$nonExistentVar + 1; // Notice error, gets caught and pretty error is displayed

$existentVar->nonExistentMethod(); // Fatal error, gets caught and pretty error is displayed

$nonExistentVar->nonExistentMethod(); // White screen, error can be seen in nginx.error.log
```

Is the last error uncatchable? Or what could the problem be?

I'm using Silex, not sure if that matters.

Comment: `if (!$nonExistentVar->nonExistentMethod()) // error` ? (also, what is the error reported by your log file?)

Comment: forgot to add.. if you are running that script just as posted and line #2 causes a fatal error, line #3 won't run

Comment: how do you handle the errors?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, exceptions can be caught but fatal errors cannot. I am curious to know how you are 'catching' the fatal error in example #2?

Why not use a php `is_a()` test to see if $nonExistentVar is of the correct class before attempting to call the method? Or possibly in conjunction with `method_exists()` if you still don't know if a class has a given method available.

Comment: He's using Silex (which uses Symfony components, including `Debug`), and it does not exactly catches the `Error`, the [Debug component](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/error_handler.html#handling-fatal-errors) uses php `set_error_handler` to send pretty response.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting only the last line:

```
$nonExistentVar->nonExistentMethod();
```

That works for me, as [Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler](https://github.com/symfony/Debug/blob/master/ExceptionHandler.php) sends the response immediately upon encountering the first `Error`:

```
public function handle(\Exception $exception)
{
    if (class_exists('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response')) {
        $this->createResponse($exception)->send();
    } else {
        $this->sendPhpResponse($exception);
    }
}
```